# Routing messages to PIDs in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, routes, erlang, erlang-otp, ets

I'm writing a server in erlang that handles very large amount of messages (records).
Each message has a tag (atom) like a user id.

The "router" will spawn a dedicated-permanent process for this user (to accumulate messages for few minutes before saving them and passing them) if such process doesn't exists. Otherwise it will pass it to the existing process mailbox as message.

The problem is the bookkeeping of a routing table.

I could think of serializing the router, each message will result in ETS lookup to find a PID by userId and eventually Spawn and ETS insert if it didn't exit. But that got congested in few seconds.

An alternative is to spawn a process directly to route each message, but that might result in race condition if a few messages to a single user came in in close sucession and didn't find their corresponding PID in ETS and spawned permanent processes. Messages will be lost and only the last spawned process will be valid (overwrite others in ETS) where the others will go idle and untracked.

I also might be thinking all wrong. is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a frequent pattern to have one process (one server) per user, just like you propose.

Sometimes, if the protocol used allows it, instead of routing the messages to a "user" process from a server listening all the users, a new process is spawned before any connection, listening (waiting) for a new user connection request. When a request arrives, a new waiting process is spawned, and the current one manages the complete session with the new user (see [learyousomeerlang: a bucket of socket](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets) for a detailed example).

Comment: Exactly. now I implemented a process per message to do the routing. and then a process per User to receive those messages. and the gen_server do the spawning and bookkeeping of user processes.  After I set Ets options according to A. Sarid answer, the solution worked just fine with real traffic.

Comment: Also you mensioned having the user process do the listenting so no routing is required. this is not possible in this case, the messages comes in from the same RPC in the form of records. would be fantastic if the message source has a socket/pid per user.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution sounds right for this case. For me, it does not sounds right to start a process for every message you get if you have large amount of messages. ETS is fast and should be able to handle large amount of data.

You might want to consider using erlang OTP `gen_server`. You can read more about it [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) , [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/what-is-otp), and [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers).

In addition, if you are going to access the ETS from many processes you might want to consider the `{read_concurrency, true}` and `{read_concurrency, true}` options. Read more about it [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets) and [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2).

Comment: Thanks.  I am using otp gen_server. I will use read_concurrency as you mentionen. and will implement a variant of the first solution. where I spawn one process per message just to do the ets lookup. and if not found then gen_server will provide a new spawned worker and update the ets table.  I will get back here to tell you how it went.